# d3 cross-linked mouseOver nodes

Tags: d3.js

I needed my circle pack to highlight matching circles on a mouseover.
was Not sure why the style is not being applied. The function is being hit ok

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/9py3v03c/)

```
   var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
   .data(nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
   //.attr("class", ".node")
   .attr("class", function(d) { return ".node " + d.AgtName; })
   .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," 
      + d.y + ")"; })
   .on("mouseover", function(d) { highlight(d.AgtName); })
   .on("mouseout", function(d) { highlight(null); });


   function highlight(agtName) {
    if (agtName == null) d3.selectAll(".node").classed("active", 
    false);
    else d3.selectAll(".node." + agtName).classed("active", true);

    console.log('agt: ' + agtName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the fill color to the node instead of the circle. Changed the class from .node to node

```
   var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
     //.attr("class", ".node")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.AgtName; })
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," 
      + d.y + ")"; })
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { highlight(d.AgtName); })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) { highlight(null); });
```

Comment: Don't use the *answer* space to make comments or additional information regarding your question. Click "edit" and edit the question instead. By the way, your fiddle link is broken.